# How to avoid duplicate logging with karma's captureConsole and spec reporter

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I need both logging and test results to be written to the console so I have

```
client {
captureConsole: true,
}
```

and

```
reporters: ['spec', 'junit'],
        specReporter: {
            maxLogLines: 5,         // limit number of lines logged per test
            suppressErrorSummary: false,  // do not print error summary
            suppressFailed: false,  // do not print information about failed tests
            suppressPassed: false,  // do not print information about passed tests
            suppressSkipped: true,  // do not print information about skipped tests
            showSpecTiming: true // print the time elapsed for each spec
        },
```

in the karma conf. But this results in each console.log to be written twice, like:

> LOG LOG: 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
>   Chrome LOG:
>   'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'

. Is there any way to configure spec reporter or karma so that console.log is not dublicated?

**UPD**: seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1873

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and ended up specifying only one reporter and that fixed it for me.  So I would recommend setting reporters to ['spec'] or ['junit'] if possible.